# Problem handling Parse users in a web app

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, parse-server, pfuser

Here is some JS code, related to handling Parse users in a web app, with unexpected behaviour.

```
......

Parse.initialize(process.env.APP_ID);
Parse.serverURL = process.env.SERVER_URL;
Parse.User.logIn(req.body.usrname, req.body.password, {
  success: user => {
    console.log("OK-OK:"+user);
    checkIfLoggedIn();
    res.render('pages/index.ejs', {});
  },
  error: (user, error) => {
    console.log("NG-NG:"+user, error);
    checkIfLoggedIn();
    res.render('pages/login.ejs', {});
  },
});

......

function checkIfLoggedIn() {
  var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
  if (currentUser) {
    console.log("Parse.User.current is A REAL USER -- logged in!!")
  } else {
    console.log("Parse.User.current is NULL -- login failed!!")
  }
}
```

Now, below is the question.
When running the code above, the messages:
*"OK-OK:"* and *"NG-NG:"* both show up in the logs as expected. But the call to the function checkIfLoggedIn() always displays a failure:

```
Parse.User.current is NULL -- login failed!!
```

Why is that? Shouldn't it display a success when we reach *"OK-OK:"*?

Comment: You can't use `Parse.User.current()` function in a Node.js environment.

Comment: OK. That was the issue then. Thanks a lot.